# Unable to use Ampersand in Campaign Builder link

Tags: google-analytics

Trying to create a campaign link to track in GA. However, our url contains ampersands (&&) `&&searchid=`so these are being cut from the campaign url. Since GA campaign links use amapersands as the variable separator, how can i get around this? I've also tried using the hex values %26 but this is also not working.

Comment: Actually there shouldn't be a problem with using ampersands - if there were campaign tagging would break the internet since ampersands are the standard delimiter for query string parameters. Can you post a url so we can see if there is some other problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the campaign tracking links anyway. For example:

```
www.example.com?utm_campaign=campaign-name&utm_source=source&utm_medium=medium
```

Would effectively be the same as if you started with something else, like this:

```
www.example.com?somequeryhere=somevalue&searchid=199&utm_campaign=campaign-name&utm_source=source&utm_medium=medium
```

As noted above, the campaign parameters for GA to work doesn't have to start with a `?` to work.

Comment: Thanks, looks like this will work:  http://www.example.com/?
utm_source=xxxx&
utm_medium=xxxx&
utm_campaign=xxxxx#&&searchid=-123

Comment: Is this your real URL? Because you have alot of spacing in it which might be causing the values to be dropped. You should remove the blank spaces in the URL, otherwise it won't work. Or perhaps you used it intentionally just now for that example?

Comment: Spaces are intentional. Putting the searchid at the end of the campaign link seems to work fine.